# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error even when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My complete error message is:

> ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in
>   WorkoutsController#create Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
>   workout_entry

The params that I am sending looks like:

```
{"workout"=>{"unit"=>"kg", "name"=>"2013-02-20T21:26:19", "note"=>nil, "workout_entry"=> [{"workout_entry_number"=>"1", "exercise_id"=>2, "entry_detail"=>[{"set_number"=>"1", "weight"=>"32", "reps"=>"43"}]}]}}
```

I have a workout that has many workout entries and each workout entries can have many entry details. The note is optional.

workout.rb

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :workout_entries, dependent: :destroy

    attr_accessible :id, :name, :note, :unit, :workout_entries_attributes
    belongs_to :user
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :workout_entries

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :unit, :inclusion => %w(kg lb)
    validates_associated :workout_entries

    default_scope order("created_at DESC")

end
```

workout_entry.rb

```
class WorkoutEntry < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :workout
    belongs_to :exercise
    has_many :entry_details, dependent: :destroy

    attr_accessible :workout_id, :exercise_id, :workout_entry_number, :entry_details_attributes
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :entry_details

    validates :exercise_id, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true}, :inclusion => { :in => 1..790 }
    validates :workout_id, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}
    validates :workout_entry_number, presence: true, numericality: {only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1}

end
```

workouts_controller.rb

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def index
        respond_with(current_user.workouts)
    end

    def show
        respond_with(current_user.workouts.find(params[:id]))
    end

    def create
        respond_with(current_user.workouts.create(params[:workout]))
    end

    def update
        @workout = current_user.workouts.find(params[:id])
        if @workout.update_attributes(params[:workout])
          render json: @workout, status: :ok
        else
          render json: @workout.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def destroy
        respond_with(current_user.workouts.destroy(params[:id]))
    end

end
```

I tried switching the ordering of attr_accessible and accepts_nested_attributes_for within the workout.rb, but it does not work.

I even tried to set

```
config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true
```

but creating was still prevented.

Comment: the error is in the params the form generates.  can you include the necessary form in the view?

Comment: I am actually using ajax to send the param so I don't have a form view.

Comment: oh ok. so you manually built the parameters in ajax? or just serialized the form? if you manually built it, just replace workout_entry with workout_entry_attributes.

Comment: Also tried to put workout_entry_attributes into attr_accessible, but it didn't work.

I changed the format of my json to use "workout_entries_attributes" and "entry_details_attributes", instead of "workout_entry" and "entry_detail".

This got rid of the mass assignment issue, but I am now getting a 422 status code.
workout_entries.workout_id ["can't be blank", "is not a number"]
workout_entries ["is invalid"] 

Workout, workout_entry, and entry_details seem to want to be created at the same time. I however, want my workout to be create first before my anything else does.

Answer (score 0):

`accepts_nested_attributes_for` does not add any attributes to the whitelist. Whatever keys your trying to pass to update_attributes have to be listed in attr_accessible, in your case you need to add `workout_entry` to `attr_accessible`.

It does look like you have an error in the form, if your using fields_for then it should be using the key `workout_entries_attributes`, which you have accessible.

Comment: I tried adding workout_entry to attr_accessible, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add workout_entry_ids in attr accessible in your workout model.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to not use accepts_nested_attributes_for in the workout and workout_entry models because it wasn't working for me. I also updated the format of my json that is sent. Details are in the link below

[link](http://pastebin.com/7Pv8BXJA)